# Is redis pubsub channels instance level or database level?

Tags: redis

Instead of storing data into redis, we use redis as our channels to sub/pub. Is this feature redis instance level or for per database?

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy enough to test:

Terminal 1: Connect to db 6 and subscribe to foo

```
> redis-cli -n 6
127.0.0.1:6379[6]> subscribe foo
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "foo"
3) (integer) 1
```

Terminal 2: Connect to db 1 and publish

```
> redis-cli -n 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> publish foo 2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]>
```

Terminal 1: Observe subscriber receiving

```
1) "message"
2) "foo"
3) "2"
```